# Need consult about convert a Java code sipnet to c#

Tags: java, c#, cryptography, des

I have following Java code:

```
static final String KEY_STRING = "MOGO_APP";

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypt)
{
    byte[] bArr = null;
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY_STRING.getBytes(), "DES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    cipher.init(2, key);
    bArr = cipher.doFinal(encrypt);
    return bArr;
}
```

I want to translate it to c#. Here is what I do:

```
const string KEY_STRING = "MOGO_APP";

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypt)
{
    byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(KEY_STRING);

    DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    cryptoProvider.Key = key;

    using (MemoryStream mm = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(mm,
            cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(encrypt, 0, encrypt.Length);
        }
        return mm.ToArray();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't give same result as the Java code.

I don't know Java. But from what I searched, I think I may have following error:

- `key` may not the same, as `KEY_STRING.getBytes()` depend on app (or system?) charset.
- The converted alogrithm may not the same with the orignal.

I also get error **`The specificed key is not valid size`**.

I'm doing step-by-step convert so I don't have sample input and output data, sorry. Would you suggest where is the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: @JoeC I already use debugger and I do know how to use it (as a mid-level programmer). Problem is I don't know Java. Please read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching and reading, I found the solution. The default cipher mode in Java is **[ECB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e10668/oracle/security/crypto/core/Cipher.html)**, while in C# is **CBC**. Bellowing is the worked code:

```
const string KEY_STRING = "MOGO_APP";

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypt)
{
    byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(KEY_STRING);

    DESCryptoServiceProvider cp = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    cp.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    cp.Key = bytes;
    ICryptoTransform i = cp.CreateDecryptor();
    return i.TransformFinalBlock(encrypt, 0, encrypt.Length); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already found your solution, it is the `getBytes()` / `GetBytes()` calls.  You need to specify explicitly what byte coding to use, and make sure that both C# and Java are using the same byte coding.  Using the system default is usually a mistake then writing across platforms.  Pick an encoding: ASCII, UTF-8 or whatever and explicitly specify it to be the same on both sides.

Comment: Found the solution. See my answer. Thank for your help!